# How to avoid merge conflicts when merging several branches?

Tags: git, github

For our project, we have a `main` branch. We each also work on our own feature branches. On a couple of occasions, I have made a feature branch, say `feature1`, off of `main`, finished up, pushed it to GitHub, and created a pull request. Before the pull request is approved, I have already branched off of `feature1` into `feature2` and I'm working on something new. Then, I push it up to GitHub and make a pull request, again. When my first pull request, `feature1`, gets approved, I then get merge conflicts in `feature2`.

1. Why does this happen? I haven't changed anything in `feature1`, just added on top of it.
2. Is there a proper way to solve this issue? I tried rebasing but that has been a very long and tedious process with fixing issues at each commit.
3. I was thinking that maybe instead of making a pull request from `feature2` into `main`, it should be into `feature1`. Would that fix it?
4. Is there a better practice to do what we are trying to accomplish?

Comment: After your merge of feature1 you should rebase your fetaure2 branch on master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use "squash merges" or "rebase and fast-forward" when merging your Oil Requests?

If so, either:

- Stop using that and use a "true merge" / "merge commit"; or
- Never base a new branch on an unmerged Pull Request

The reason is that whenever you squash or rebase a branch, you are *throwing away* the commits that were originally on that branch, and creating new ones *with no recorded relationship* to the originals. If you've based later work on those original commits, *git thinks those commits are still unmerged*, and when you try to merge the later work, it tries to apply changes that have already been made, pretty much guaranteeing some confusing conflicts.

You *can* recreate the second branch by rebasing it onto the squashed / rebased commits on main, but the more often you "chain" branches together (starting from a previous feature rather than main) the more work you make for yourself keeping them in sync.

If you use a true merge, git *knows* how the branches relate, and not to apply the same changes twice.